# cannot create a face from a vertex

Tags: faces, shortcut

I'm new to blender apologies if this is a silly question, however I am trying to create a octagon face from the middle vertex of a cube, this is done in a video I was watching. I believe its an 'inset from vertex' however I'm unsure... can anyone help.. the picture below shows what I want to do, the selected face seems to be originating from the middle vertex.

Video I was watching is here and the timestamp is 0:22 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7noD3zrk7Y&t=49s

[image]

Comment: You need to use the bevel tool for the Vertex: Select the Vertex and press CTRL + SHIFT + B

Answer (score 1):

In the video he is using the beveling for vertecies tool . For doing this,select the vertex and press Shift + ctrl + b

[image]

[image]